# WinDivert: changing GET request in tcp packet

Tags: python, tcp, wfp

I'm trying to change simple GET request with pydivert (WinDivert for python)

What i seem to encounter is problem with packet lenght.
when i rewrite url so it has same amount or less of letters it works:
ie. `GET /?a=asdf` => `GET /?a=z`

But when i add more letters to the request, browser loops and ends up 
without showing anything

Below is example code i use

```
filter_ = "true and tcp.PayloadLength > 0" 
with Handle(filter=filter_) as handle:

 while True:

        packet = handle.receive()

        if packet.payload[0:3]=="GET":
            packet.payload=packet.payload.replace("GET /?a=asdf","GET /?a=gfdsazzz")
        handle.send(packet)
```

and

```
<?php
  echo $_GET['a'];
?>
```

Is there somewhere a MAX packet size setted. If yes then how to increase it?

If that would be a hint for you then if i will print all packets in console
then i clearly see that request was responded by server because see packet.payload with `gfdsazzz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you did not update the TCP/IP headers to reflect the new packet length.

However, there are other more serious problems:

1. As you mentioned, the new packet may exceed the maximum packet size (MTU)
2. The TCP Seq/Ack numbers need to be changed, and will no longer be in sync between both ends of the connection.
3. EDIT: Another problem is that the URL may be split between multiple packets, especially for long URLs.

The second and third problems can not be fixed easily.

If you wish to modify TCP streams with WinDivert, a far better solution is to use WinDivert to redirect the traffic to a local proxy server, and have the proxy server edit the stream.  For an example program that uses this idea, see [TorWall](https://github.com/basil00/TorWall).